# Is there a way to disable the audit for stageid field on a CRM entity that's enabled for auditing?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

Got a custom entity which has auditing enabled. Every time an user changes the stage on the Business process flow (BPF) on that entity, it's generating an audit log record with the change in the *stageid* which is irrelevant for the business and i cannot use the *modifiedon* field since the stage change is changing the *modifiedon* field data as well, which makes the data irrelevant for the business.[image]

Comment: While in general auditing can be enabled or disabled per field, it looks like StageId is a managed field and its Audit setting cannot be changed. What is it that you're ultimately trying to do? It seems that changing the stage of a record should definitely count as modifying it...

Comment: @Aron, two things I'm after. 1) whenever a stage is changed a log is getting created irrespective of any other data changes I don't want to go through too many irrelevant logs while going through the audit summary logs. 2) I don't want the _modifiedon_ field to be updated when a stage gets changed on the BPF as this makes the _modifiedon_ field irrelevant for our business needs. It should only get updated when the actual business data gets updated.

Comment: OK, I hear what you're saying. One idea would be to create a field called Business Data Modified On. Then, create a workflow that runs on change of the fields you consider to be business data and have the workflow set the new field to the current time.

Comment: Perfect solution! @Aron. This fixes part of the problem. do you think  a possible solution exists where auditing is disabled for the field stageid?. how to mark your comment as answer?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea would be to create a field called Business Data Modified On. Then, create a workflow that runs on change of the fields you consider to be business data and have the workflow set the new field to the current time.

It does not appear that Auditing can be disabled on the managed field StageId.